# why javascript library cannot be found when imported in html page deployed in Tomcat7?

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat

I have a web service project in eclipse, and i deploy it to Tomcat by right clicking on the project and click on run on server. The following script tag is in one of the html pages:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../assests/js/lib/yui_3.6.0pr3/yui/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
```

The html page is located in folder called `SamplePages` which is contained in the folder `TEST-WS/production`, the folder `assets` is also in `TEST-WS/production`.
When i open this page in the browser, i get the following JS error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/TEST-WS/production/assests/js/lib/yui_3.6.0pr3/yui/build/yui/yui-min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The path `TEST-WS/production/assests/js/lib/yui_3.6.0pr3/yui/build/yui/yui-min.js` is correct and the .js file is there. I have other scripts like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/lib/all-concat.js"></script>
```

but it works fine. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
src="../assests/js
src="../assets/js
```

One of those paths is probably wrong.

Comment: the first one is wrong...my bad, have been looking at it for the last half an hour but could not spot it.. thanks